# coloring sectors in barplot using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have generated a bar graph representing global conservation of each position of the matrix. In addition, three different sectors are identified for some positions. How can I color those sectors differently within the bar plot?

Note: there are multiple questions with the similar title but I was unable to find my solution out of those.

Comment: Very unclear question. Show some of the code you use to generate the figure. Show the figure you have if possible. Explain in more details what do you want. Don't expect other to read your mind. You have to work on question to get quick and useful answers, as well as to increase your reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you mean:
http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-17DC8/?solution=1-17DC8
alternatively split your data into three parts, plot each one of them with the color you want using `hold on`
for example:

```
bar(1:10,1:10,'FaceColor','red');hold on;bar(11:20,1:10,'FaceColor','blue');hold off
```